# Unable to use indexOf on a Typed Array due to TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have defined an `Interface`, created an array of `type Interface` and am now attempting to use `.indexOf`, a method of an Array, and I am getting IDE error complaints that make no sense to me. Hoping someone here may be able to lend a thought to solve this pickle.

#### Interface

```
export interface IAddress {
  name: string,
  registrationId: number
}
```

#### Code

```
let friends: IAddress[];

// assume friends has a few elements...

let index = friends.indexOf((friend: IAddress) => {
  return !!(friend.name === 'some name');
});
```

#### TypeScript Errors:

```
Argument of type '(friend: IAddress) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IAddress'.
Type '(friend: IAddress) => boolean' is missing the following properties from type 'IAddress': registrationId
```

If I were to remove the `:IAddress` from the typed def next to `friend:` I see this error instead.

```
Argument of type '(friend: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IAddress'.
Type '(friend: any) => boolean' is missing the following properties from type 'IAddress': registrationId
```

Comment: @Dale Burell -- Would like to know why I can't have a formal gesture of thanks in a question? It's just a bit of nice etiquette and attitude towards fellow developers.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Array.prototype.indexOf()` receives a parameter `searchElement` and a second optional parameter `fromIndex`.

- Here is [the API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Updated answer based on @Pixxl comment to use [Array.prototype. findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get `index` variable:

```
const friends: IAddress[];

// assume friends has a few elements...
const index = friends.findIndex((friend: IAddress) => friend.name === 'some name');
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize `index` and `indexOf` are meant for primitive values whereas `find` and `findIndex` are meant for more object-like values. I'd also like to suggest changing this answer to one that uses `findIndex` instead as it accomplishes the same task without needing to declare an `index` var outside the scope.

Comment: Great comment @Pixxl, thank you.. Edidting the answer to use `Array.prototoype.findIndex()`...